# Difficulty getting Arduino data via puTTY

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am working on a project with a simple particulate matter sensor hooked up to an Arduino Uno. I'm using puTTY to log the sensor's output. My Arduino program converts the data to a numerical format, then prints it to the serial monitor every 30 to 31 seconds. I want to use puTTY to log this data to a file over a period of weeks. My problem now is that when I run it using puTTY, it stops after about 30-90 mins and "Fatal error: error reading from serial device" pops up. The wires connecting my sensor to the Arduino, and the USB cable connecting the Arduino to my computer all appear fine. Here is the code on the Arduino:

```
int pin = 8;
unsigned long duration;
unsigned long starttime;
unsigned long sampletime_ms = 30000; 
unsigned long lowpulseoccupancy = 0;
float ratio = 0;
float concentration = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(8,INPUT);
  starttime = millis();
  Serial.print("Data is collected roughly every ");
  Serial.print(sampletime_ms/1000);
  Serial.println(" seconds.");
}

void loop() {
  duration = pulseIn(pin, LOW);
  lowpulseoccupancy = lowpulseoccupancy+duration;
  if ((millis()-starttime) >= sampletime_ms)
  {
    ratio = lowpulseoccupancy/(sampletime_ms);
    concentration = 1.1*pow(ratio,3)-3.8*pow(ratio,2)+520*ratio+0.62;
    Serial.print("Concentration = ");
    Serial.print(concentration);
    Serial.print(" pcs/0.01cf at ");
    Serial.print(millis()/1000);
    Serial.println(" seconds.");
    lowpulseoccupancy = 0;
    starttime = millis();
  }
}
```

I'm using the shinyei PPD42 particulate matter sensor.
Can anyone tell me what's going on, and if there's any sort of workaround I can use? I don't necessarily need to use puTTY, I just need to log the serial output from my Arduino.
Thanks!

Comment: Genuine Uno or a Chinese clone with a CH340G USB chip?

Comment: It's a genuine Uno board.

Comment: Does this happen if you use Arduino Serial Monitor only?